# Power BI - change existing visuals

Tags: powerbi

I would like to modify the existing table visual to add a text instead of the whole URL when showing a column as a URL.

I modified it to my needs in Visual Studio, it works, but how would I export it to pbwiz, in order to use it in Power BI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating our built-in visual into a visual you can use through our developer tools will require you to trace many dependencies and integrate those into a single .ts file.  I think it would be better to share your repo and approach with us by [filing an issue in the Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals repo](https://github.com/microsoft/powerBI-visuals/issues) and we'd figure out if the change you're making is generic enough to include in the base repo.

Comment: For starters, I just wanted to add the possibility to show a custom text instead of the whole hyperlink in the table visual. Do you think this might be a future addition to the table visual ?

Comment: That is something we're looking at.  Could you submit an idea at https://ideas.powerbi.com

Comment: For TableEx - add ann option to NOT lazy load the date, so I can export it afterwards using powerBI-Javascript without any issues. I would like to have an option that would allow me to load all the data, without lazy load.